# XPath from Chrome not working on Microsoft Edge

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge

I've wrote a script to test a website and I've taken the Xpath from google chrome for all the elements and I wanted to test it on Microsoft Edge, but whenever I run it, I get a `org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession` error. So my guess is that It's not able to find the element on Edge.

```
public class testing
{
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlreporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("D:\\Selenium\\test_report.html");
    ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
    ExtentTest test;
    JavascriptExecutor jse;
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");

        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlreporter);

        jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        extent.setSystemInfo("Browseer", "Microsoft Edge");
        extent.setSystemInfo("OS", "Windows 10");

        driver.get("https://www.hoteltreeoflife.com/reservation"); 
    }
    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        test = extent.createTest("Test Case 1 : Selecting the dates", "Clicking check availabiluty with default dates");

        test.info("Finding Check Availability");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/button")).click(); //<-- This is the element
        test.info("Clicks on Check Availability");

        String title = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("Choose Your Room"));
        test.info("Successfully selected dates");
    }
}
```

I also couldn't find a way to get the Xpath on Edge.

**EDIT:**

This is the full error:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite

[VerboseTestNG] RUNNING: Suite: "Command line test" containing "1" Tests (config: null)
[VerboseTestNG] INVOKING CONFIGURATION: "Command line test" - @BeforeTest newpackage.testing.setup()
[16:46:55.985] - Listening on http://localhost:4848/ 
Jul 26, 2017 4:46:57 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
[VerboseTestNG] PASSED CONFIGURATION: "Command line test" - @BeforeTest newpackage.testing.setup() finished in 4794 ms
[VerboseTestNG] INVOKING: "Command line test" - newpackage.testing.test1()
[VerboseTestNG] FAILED: "Command line test" - newpackage.testing.test1() finished in 303 ms
[VerboseTestNG] java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
[VerboseTestNG]     at newpackage.testing.test1(testing.java:53)
[VerboseTestNG] INVOKING CONFIGURATION: "Command line test" - @AfterMethod newpackage.testing.check(org.testng.ITestResult)(value(s): [TestResult name=test1 status=FAILURE method=testing.test1()[pri:0, instance:newpackage.testing@59e84876] output={null}])
[VerboseTestNG] PASSED CONFIGURATION: "Command line test" - @AfterMethod newpackage.testing.check(org.testng.ITestResult)(value(s): [TestResult name=test1 status=FAILURE method=testing.test1()[pri:0, instance:newpackage.testing@59e84876] output={null}]) finished in 462 ms
[VerboseTestNG] INVOKING CONFIGURATION: "Command line test" - @AfterTest newpackage.testing.close()
[16:47:03.511] - Stopping server.
[VerboseTestNG] PASSED CONFIGURATION: "Command line test" - @AfterTest newpackage.testing.close() finished in 3788 ms
[VerboseTestNG] 
[VerboseTestNG] ===============================================
[VerboseTestNG]     Command line test
[VerboseTestNG]     Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
[VerboseTestNG] ===============================================

===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Java Result: 1
```

Comment: What is the full error? Its rather that it cannot even connect to Edge.

Comment: I don't think it is related to finding element.

Comment: @TamasHegedus It connects with Edge and it opens the URL but the test fails when it comes to clicking on the element `driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/button")).click();`

Comment: @Tuks Sorry I forgot to post the entire error. I've posted the full error now.

Comment: So the error is in fact has nothing to do with `org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession`. I would recommend to first open the page in Edge and check the presence of that element by hand.

Comment: Maybe try using relative xpath instead of absolute path? Could You show html of website?

Comment: The "error" is not an error but a failed assertion. You should spend some time reading up on TestNG, how it works, some tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To click on the button **`Check availability`** instead of the absolute path which you used:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/button")).click();
```

Consider using the following unique logical `xpath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block']")).click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is use an explicit wait, should fix the problem if it has not already.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(""/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/button"")));
element.click();
```

Use it instead of finding element, easier to turn into into a method so you can call it whenever. Hope it helps